# How to customize the selection custom bar in android webview for all versions

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am doing project based on epub reader. here to read a page I have use webview to load the html page. When the user selects a text it should be highlighted and the menu bar should appear with the option as in Android4.0. This can be done easily in android4.0 since its a predefined option for android4.0. But how can I do this in earlier versions of Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this page helps 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html